# N/currentRecord module does not exist when uploading User Event script to NetSuite (SuiteScript 2.0)

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am trying to upload the below script to NetSuite in order to do a currency conversion from the purchase order currency to USD.

I would like a custom field to be updated with the USD amount whenever a user keys in any items into a purchase order.

When I upload the script, I receive the following error message:

> Fail to evaluate script: {"type":"error.SuiteScriptModuleLoaderError","name":"MODULE_DOES_NOT_EXIST","message":"Module does not exist: N/currentRecord.js","stack":[]}**

Would greatly appreciate some guidance. Thank you.

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NModuleScope Public
 *@NScriptType UserEventScript
 */

define(['N/currency', 'N/currentRecord'],function(currency, currentRecord) {
        function POCurrencyConversion() {
            var Fixed_Currency = 'USD';
            var Transaction_Currency = currentRecord.getValue('currency');
            var Tx_currency_total = currentRecord.getValue('total');
            var rate = currency.exchangeRate({
                source: Transaction_Currency,
                target: Fixed_Currency
            });
            var ConvertedAmount = Tx_currency_total * rate;
            currentRecord.setValue('custbody_po_total_usd',ConvertedAmount)
        }
        POCurrencyConversion();
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In User Events, you do not need the `currentRecord` module. Rather, you can retrieve the record in context from the parameter that NetSuite passes into your event handler function:

```
function beforeSubmit(context) {
    var Transaction_Currency = context.newRecord.getValue({fieldId: "currency"});
    var Tx_currency_total = context.newRecord.getValue({fieldId: "total"});
    // etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use "N/currentRecord" module in User Event Script.
This module is supported in Client Script.
instead you can make use of context.newRecord.